# ¿Como puedo sumar el value de varias opciones, cuando sean seleecionadas?

Tags: html, jquery

Estoy tratando de montar como un formulario, con varias opciones `select`, donde se seleccione un rango de edad, dependiendo del rango seleccionado, otorgará un `value` el cual sería el monto por el rango de edad.

Después vendrían dos opciones, de **si** y **no**, de las cuales si escoge **si**, el `value` es 24 si es **no** entonces es 0.

Para el primero logro crear el `select` y sus opciones, les doy su `value`, pero cuando quiero proceder con la suma, no sé como escribirlo.

En el caso de las opciones **si/no**, pensé en usar booleanos, pero como indiqué soy nuevo, entiendo la teoría pero me falta práctica, agradezco su ayuda. Esto es sólo un proyecto personal para agilizar una parte en mi trabajo.

```html
<pre>
    <h2>Seleccione el Rango de Edad:</h2>
    
    <select id="diezk" onchange="select()">
        <option value="180">4-18</option>
        <option value="230">19-22</option>
        <option value="360">23-29</option>
        <option value="420">30-37</option>
    </select>
    
    <h2>Desea usar </h2> 

    <select id="asit" onchange="select()">
        <option value="24">Si</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>

    <h2>Desea usar </h2> 

    <select id="fun" onchange="select()">
        <option value="24">Si</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
</pre>
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Pero como los quieres sumar, con que evento? el click de un boton? cuando seleccione la opcion (change), debes ser mas especifico con el problema, lee [ask]

Comment: Si , cuando se seleccione una opcion, se sumen el value,

opcion 1 , selecciono el option dos, value= 230
opcion 2 , selecciono si, value = 23
opcion 3, selecciono no, value = 0

total = 253

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción que te propongo es que a todos los `select` les pongas la misma clase y en `jQuery` podrías obtener los `value` seleccionados dentro de un ciclo `each`, se obtiene la suma y se pasa el resultado a donde lo necesites. *En mi caso en un `input`.*

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es agregar un `option` con `value` 0 y con el atributo `hidden` para que se oculte una vez seleccionada otra opción. Esto es para evitar errores en el cálculo del total.

```js
function calcular(){
  //Inicializar la suma en cero
  let suma = 0;
  //Recorrer todos los select con clase lista
  $('.lista').each(function( i ) {
    //Obtener el value seleccionado en cada select
    let valorSeleccionado = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    //Incrementar o decrementar el valor de suma
    suma = parseInt(suma) + parseInt(valorSeleccionado);
  });
  //Asignar la suma al campo donde se muestran los resultados
  $('#total').val(suma);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
    <h2>Seleccione el Rango de Edad:</h2>
    
    <select class="lista" onchange="calcular()">
        <option value="0" hidden>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="180">4-18</option>
        <option value="230">19-22</option>
        <option value="360">23-29</option>
        <option value="420">30-37</option>
    </select>
    
    <h2>Desea usar </h2> 

    <select class="lista" onchange="calcular()">
        <option value="0" hidden>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="24">Si</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>

    <h2>Desea usar </h2> 

    <select class="lista" onchange="calcular()">
        <option value="0" hidden>Seleccione</option>
        <option value="24">Si</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
    </select>
    
    <h2>Total</h2>
    <input id="total" value="0"/>
</pre>
```